# How do I style text in Android Java when it originates in strings.xml?

Tags: android

I'm trying to put a multi-paragraph message in an AlertDialog and have blank lines between the three (short) paragraphs. It works great when the string is written in my Java code but fails miserably when the string originates in strings.xml. What do I have to do differently when the text comes from strings.xml?

Please note that the value of message999 in my strings.xml is exactly what is in the commented-out message variable in my Java code.

Here's my code.

```
private void displayEmptySetMessage() {

    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.message999), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListSales.this);

    //Set the message.
    //String message = "<p>There are currently no sales in the table.</p><br><p>If this is normal - you may have deleted all of your sales - and you wish to add rows with the add feature, please press Proceed.</p><br><p>If you think something is wrong, press Exit and contact your system administrator.</p>";
    String message = getString(R.string.message999);
    CharSequence styledMessage  = Html.fromHtml(message, Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL);
    builder.setMessage(styledMessage);

    //Set the title.
    builder.setTitle("No Sales");

    //Add the buttons
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.proceed, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked Proceed button - do nothing except dismiss the dialog
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.exit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //User clicked Exit button - notify the system administrator and exit the app
            Toast.makeText(ListSales.this, R.string.message009, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //placeholder
            java.lang.System.exit(0);
        }
    });


    //Create and display the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the commented out string is sufficient for what you want, there are a couple of easy ways you could generate it (without html formatting).

You could include newline characters in the strings.xml file, as in

```
<string name="mymessage">This is paragraph 1.\n\n\nThis is paragraph 2.\n\n\nThis is the last paragraph.</string>
```

or you could separate the paragraphs in the XML file

```
<string name="message_par1">This is paragraph 1.</string>
<string name="message_par2">This is paragraph 1.</string>
<string name="message_par3">This is the last paragraph.</string>
```

and assemble the full message in your code

```
String message = getString(R.string.message_par1) + "\n\n\n" +
                 getString(R.string.message_par2) + "\n\n\n" +
                 getString(R.string.message_par3);
builder.setMessage(message);
```

This doesn't let you do any html formatting, but if you were just trying to mimic the string you had commented out this should work.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! It's too bad they have to handle the two cases so differently but at least there's a way to do it that isn't too painful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create the message like this.

```
String message = "Paragraph1" + "\n\n\n" +
"Paragraph 2" + "\n\n\n" + 
"Paragraph 3"

builder.setMessage(message);
```